# Simplified Dynamic Arithmetic Operator

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm revisiting this old project I tackled a while back where I wanted to avoid using if statements and switch blocks to render say a simple calculation where the operator ( `+` / `-` / `/` / `*` ) could be anything.

I am retrieving data from a database (securely inserted), along with a beta case of user input (again, painstakingly secured with validation) via ajax. That works fine, yay, great. Now we come to the demon I've heard so much about. `eval()`.

If you take the time to read up, modern browsers using something like the V8 engine can cache the compiled eval. People say it creates vulnerability via injection. If you offer efficient validation and avoid any critical application mis-structures, how can it be harmful?

```
//note I'm using var just for clarity, this is NOT the declaration or assignment statment
//also note the variables are stored in an array because the condition can be dynamic in size, but that's overhead for now

var firstNum = 50;
var secondNum = 100;
var operator = "+";
var condition = firstNum+operator+secondNum;

if (eval(condition) > 149) { //not the real condition, just an example
    console.log("Success");
}
```

Is this still not safe? Is it more efficient than a switch statement? Nested if statements? If performance isn't an issue and you do know what you're doing, can `eval()` be good, and not.. wait for it.. `evil()`?

Note: Yes I have seen the other questions about `eval()` yet I still haven't found a reason for this to even exist because people treat it like a leper.

This basically comes down to: what is the best way to handle a condition where the mathematical operator is not a static value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`eval` is harmful partly because

- you have to be rather careful in order to avoid code injection.
- most IDEs can't catch stupid syntax errors in a dynamically built string.
- it has historically sucked performancewise.
- it's basically using a sledgehammer to swat a fly, which is the big cause of a lot of the other reasons.  Very, *very* few situations benefit from that much flexibility, and most just get worse.

In this case, you could do something like

```
var operators = {
    '+' : function(a, b) { return a + b; },
    '-' : function(a, b) { return a - b; },
    '*' : function(a, b) { return a * b; },
    '/' : function(a, b) { return a / b; },
};

var firstNum = 50;
var secondNum = 100;
var op = operators['+'];

if (op(firstNum, secondNum) > 149) {
    console.log('Success');
}
```

and end up with all the dynamism you're looking for with your `eval`, with none of the downsides.  You get to define exactly what operations you want to allow, and what's more, you're not even limited to infix operators -- you could have a 'max' operator, or a 'round', for example.

Comment: Now, what if the statement uses multiple operators and there's an array of numbers?

Comment: @RUJordan: You'd have to show a realistic example where that'd be done.  I could invent all kinds of arbitrary scenarios where `eval` could be useful, but almost all of them would be contrived for that purpose, and wouldn't happen in reality.  The only situations where it'd really happen, are also some of the most dangerous (JS code straight out of a database, for example).